# get access to variable in directive from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a directive, I´m using in my template:

```
<data-input> </data-input>
```

In my directive (dataInput) I have the template (...data-input.html).
In that template the html-code says:

```
<input ng-change="dataChanged()" ... > ...
```

In the JavaScript it says:

```
scope.dataChanged= function(){ //change the data }
```

Works perfectly, but know I need to safe the changed data to a variable in my controller (that has a different scope of course).
The template, where I put the `<data-input> </data-input>` belongs to the final scope, I´m trying to reach.

I tried it via parameter, but it didnt work.
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some more code? Where is your controller defined? Does it wrap your directive?

Comment: If you provide the code of your directive, we'll be able to help you out. Sounds like this is going to be dependent on how you're implementing the directive. Have you included a Controller, or doing everything in the link function?

Answer (score 0):

Here are your options:

1. You can nest controllers if possible. This will create scope inheritance and you will be able to share variables of the parent.
2. You can use `$rootscope` from both the controllers to share data. Your `dataChanged` function can save anything to the `$rootscope`
3. You can use `angular.element` to get the scope of any element. `angular.element('data-input').scope()` returns it's cope.
4. This is not recommended. But there are circumstances in which people use global space to communicate between angular and non-angular code. But I don't think this is your case.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Angular Watches to see changes is some variable, like this

eg:

```
$scope.$watch('age + name', function () {
  //called when variables 'name' or 'age' changed
  //Or you can use just 'age'
});
```